# "warning: control reaches end of non-void function" in a simple for-loop (GCC)

Tags: c

Take a look at the following code:

```cpp
int foo(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i != 1; i = 1) {
        return i;
    }
}
```

GCC 10.2 with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99` emits the following warning:

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

If I don't miss something, `foo` obviously terminates -- it will always return 0.

How to fix this warning? I can't use GCC diagnostic pragmas because the above for-loop is actually generated by a macro which must be a statement prefix, so I can't just `_Pragma("GCC diagnostic pop")` after a user-provided statement (`{ return i; }` in the above example).

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/E8EKqPf6c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your assumption that the code in the function you have shown can *never* reach beyond the `for` loop and, thus, the "invalid return" cannot be executed. However, many (most) compilers won't accept this as a reason to not emit the warning. (Similar situations can arise when you have `if` and `else if` blocks that cover ***all*** possibilities, yet still omit a 'terminal' `else` block.

> *How to fix this warning?*

Simply add a `return 42;` statement (the value of the integer literal can be anything you like) at the end of the function.

As a point of interest, the "clang-cl" code analysis tool gives *two* warnings: one that the `for` loop never runs past its first iteration, and one about control reaching the end of a non-void function (like your GCC warning) :

> warning : non-void function does not return a value in all control
> paths [-Wreturn-type] warning : loop will run at most once (loop
> increment never executed) [-Wunreachable-code-loop-increment]

These are things you have to learn to live with: compilers can't always *reliably* predict all possible outcomes, even though a human reader can see what's really happening.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: You can also put `__builtin_unreachable()` at the end, but this is compiler specific.

Comment: @interjay Indeed - that would make the code much clearer, at the expense of more characters. (But I would add a comment after the `return 42;` statement, anyways.)